# Are we going to get the same SID if we delete an account and recreate it with exactly same parameters?

Tags: windows, sid

I am learning Windows security management and how it is managed by assigning SID token. My Question is:

> Will the SIDs be same if i delete an account and then recreate it with all the same parameters?

Answer (score 1):

No, even if you create excactly as the old one it will have a new SID. It's the same with all objects not just with users.

Comment: can u tell why? is this is due to the fact that SIDs are generated by seeding random number through time?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

This is Microsoft's answer: SIDs are unique within their scope (domain or local) and are never reused.

Please read this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778824%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Cheers!